# How to use template module with different set of variables?

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

My use case is the following :

I have a template file, and I would like to create 2 different files from that template, with the variables being filled by a different set of variables for each file.

For example, lets say I want to template the file containing the line:

```
mkdir -p {{myTemplateVariable}}
```

I would like to find a proper way to get this variable filled by "File1" and "File2". Something like :

```
- name: template test 1
  template: 
        src=myTemplateFile
        dest=result1


- name: template test 2
  template: 
        src=myTemplateFile
        dest=result2
```

where I could specify for the first templating that the variable to use is a = "File1" and for the second, b = "File2".

Comment: Is that exactly that I do with all my recipes, look this comment http://stackoverflow.com/a/40189525/1571310, hope this help!

Answer (score 79, accepted):

For Ansible 2.x:

```yaml
    - name: template test
      template: 
        src: myTemplateFile
        dest: result1
      vars:
        myTemplateVariable: File1

    - name: template test
      template: 
        src: myTemplateFile
        dest: result2
      vars:
        myTemplateVariable: File2
```

---

For Ansible 1.x:

Unfortunately the `template` module does not support passing variables to it, which can be used inside the template. There was a [feature request](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/4546) but it was rejected.

I can think of two workarounds:

**1. Include**

The `include` statement supports passing variables. So you could have your `template` task inside an extra file and include it twice with appropriate parameters:

my_include.yml:

```
- name: template test
  template: 
        src=myTemplateFile
        dest=destination
```

main.yml:

```
- include: my_include.yml destination=result1 myTemplateVariable=File1

- include: my_include.yml destination=result2 myTemplateVariable=File2
```

**2. Re-define myTemplateVariable**

Another way would be to simply re-define myTemplateVariable right before every `template` task.

```
- set_fact:
     myTemplateVariable: File1

- name: template test 1
  template: 
        src=myTemplateFile
        dest=result1

- set_fact:
     myTemplateVariable: File2

- name: template test 2
  template: 
        src=myTemplateFile
        dest=result2
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, is it really impossible to do without workarounds? I am currently tryng something like : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26020465/ansible-with-dict-template-use, but still having some errors (maybe not directly related).

Comment: Yes, you can do it with a loop as well - still it is a workaround. :)

Comment: not required anymore.  "vars" is now supported. see @konstantin-suvorov answer below.

Comment: thanks for the `set_fact` tip

Answer (score 136):

With Ansible 2.x you can use `vars:` with tasks.

Template `test.j2`:

```yaml
mkdir -p {{myTemplateVariable}}
```

Playbook:

```yaml
- template: src=test.j2 dest=/tmp/File1
  vars:
    myTemplateVariable: myDirName

- template: src=test.j2 dest=/tmp/File2
  vars:
    myTemplateVariable: myOtherDir
```

This will pass different `myTemplateVariable` values into test.j2.

Comment: initially i made a mistake and had vars: indented like the rest of the template arguments (like src:).  I guess the indent level means vars: is of the task, not the template.  So you can do this anywhere, not just templates. nice.

Answer (score 47):

You can do this very easy, look my Supervisor recipe:

```
- name: Setup Supervisor jobs files
  template:
    src: job.conf.j2
    dest: "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/{{ item.job }}.conf"
    owner: root
    group: root
    force: yes
    mode: 0644
  with_items:
    - { job: bender, arguments: "-m 64", instances: 3 }
    - { job: mailer, arguments: "-m 1024", instances: 2 }
  notify: Ensure Supervisor is restarted
```

job.conf.j2:

```
[program:{{ item.job }}]
user=vagrant
command=/usr/share/nginx/vhosts/parclick.com/app/console rabbitmq:consumer {{ item.arguments }} {{ item.job }} -e prod
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
numprocs={{ item.instances }}
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/{{ item.job }}.stderr.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/{{ item.job }}.stdout.log
```

Output:

```
TASK [Supervisor : Setup Supervisor jobs files] ********************************
changed: [loc.parclick.com] => (item={u'instances': 3, u'job': u'bender', u'arguments': u'-m 64'})
changed: [loc.parclick.com] => (item={u'instances': 2, u'job': u'mailer', u'arguments': u'-m 1024'})
```

Enjoy!

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer. Since its supported now

Answer (score 23):

This is a solution/hack I'm using:

tasks/main.yml:

```
- name: parametrized template - a
  template:
    src: test.j2
    dest: /tmp/templateA
  with_items: var_a

- name: parametrized template - b
  template:
    src: test.j2
    dest: /tmp/templateB
  with_items: var_b
```

vars/main.yml

```
var_a:
  - 'this is var_a'
var_b:
  - 'this is var_b'
```

templates/test.j2:

```
{{ item }}
```

After running this, you get `this is var_a` in /tmp/templateA and `this is var_b` in /tmp/templateB.

Basically you abuse `with_items` to render the template with each item in the one-item list. This works because you can control what the list is when using `with_items`.

The downside of this is that you have to use `item` as the variable name in you template.

If you want to pass more than one variable this way, you can dicts as your list items like this:

```
var_a:
  -
    var_1: 'this is var_a1'
    var_2: 'this is var_a2'
var_b:
  -
    var_1: 'this is var_b1'
    var_2: 'this is var_b2'
```

and then refer to them in your template like this:

```
{{ item.var_1 }}
{{ item.var_2 }}
```

Comment: Clean solution, but hat to use `with_items: '{{ var_a }}'`

Answer (score 9):

I did it in this way.

In tasks/main.yml

```
- name: template test
  template: 
        src=myTemplateFile.j2
        dest={{item}}
   with_dict: some_dict
```

and in vars/main.yml

```
some_dict:
  /path/to/dest1:
    var1: 1
    var2: 2
  /path/to/dest2:
    var1: 3
    var2: 4
```

and in templates/myTemplateFile.j2

```
some_var = {{ item.value.var1 }}
some_other_var = {{ item.value.var2 }}
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: `with_dict` is the better solution.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem to solve, here is a simple solution of how to pass variables to template files, the trick is to write the template file taking advantage of the variable. You need to create a dictionary (list is also possible), which holds the set of variables corresponding to each of the file. Then within the template file access them.

see below:

```
the template file: test_file.j2
# {{ ansible_managed }} created by xbalaji@gmail.com

{% set dkey  = (item | splitext)[0]  %}
{% set fname = test_vars[dkey].name  %}
{% set fip   = test_vars[dkey].ip    %}
{% set fport = test_vars[dkey].port  %}
filename: {{ fname }}
ip address: {{ fip }}
port: {{ fport }}
```

the playbook

```
---
#
# file: template_test.yml
# author: xbalaji@gmail.com
#
# description: playbook to demonstrate passing variables to template files
#
# this playbook will create 3 files from a single template, with different
# variables passed for each of the invocation
#
# usage:
# ansible-playbook -i "localhost," template_test.yml

- name: template variables testing
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    ansible_connection: local
    dest_dir: "/tmp/ansible_template_test/"
    test_files:
      - file_01.txt
      - file_02.txt
      - file_03.txt
    test_vars:
      file_01:
        name: file_01.txt
        ip: 10.0.0.1
        port: 8001
      file_02:
        name: file_02.txt
        ip: 10.0.0.2
        port: 8002
      file_03:
        name: file_03.txt
        ip: 10.0.0.3
        port: 8003

  tasks:
    - name: copy the files
      template:
        src: test_file.j2
        dest: "{{ dest_dir }}/{{ item }}"
      with_items:
        - "{{ test_files }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- name: copy vhosts
  template: src=site-vhost.conf dest=/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/{{ item }}.conf
  with_items:
    - somehost.local
    - otherhost.local
  notify: restart apache
```

IMPORTANT: Note that an item does not have to be just a string, it can be an object with as many properties as you like, so that way you can pass any number of variables.

In the template I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@example.org
    ServerName {{ item }}
    DocumentRoot /vagrant/public


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-{{ item }}.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: How could I make it an object?

Answer (score 1):

Another real world example using a list

an extract for a template for php.ini

```
{% if 'cli/php.ini' in item.d %}
max_execution_time = 0
memory_limit = 1024M
{% else %}
max_execution_time = 300
memory_limit = 512M
{% endif %}
```

This is the var

```
php_templates:
  - { s: 'php.ini.j2', d: "/etc/php/{{php_version}}/apache2/php.ini" }
  - { s: 'php.ini.j2', d: "/etc/php/{{php_version}}/cli/php.ini" }
```

Then i deploy with this

```
- name: push templated files
  template:
    src: "{{item.s}}"
    dest: "{{item.d}}"
    mode: "{{item.m | default(0644) }}"
    owner: "{{item.o | default('root') }}"
    group: "{{item.g | default('root') }}"
    backup: yes
  with_items: "{{php_templates}}"
```