# Write same template to two different files, changing one value

Tags: templates, ansible

I would like to write the same Ansible template to two different files, one with a value in the file set to True, and the other with a value set to False.

What's the best way to do this? My instinct was to try and pass a value in the `template:` directive. However, [it seems like this is frowned upon](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/4546).

One way would be to have two different jinja files with almost entirely the same contents; one has the value set to True and the other False.

Another way would be to define a variable, write one template, then use `set_fact` to change the variable's value, then write the second file. This also seems a little cumbersome.

Another would be to have the template detect what filename it's being rendered as, somehow? And branch in the template based on that.

I must be missing something obvious.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use template module with different set of variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31142369/how-to-use-template-module-with-different-set-of-variables)

Answer (score 0):

With Ansible 2.x you can use `vars:` with tasks:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - template: src=my_template.j2 dest=out1.txt
      vars:
        name: John
    - template: src=my_template.j2 dest=out2.txt
      vars:
        name: Jane
```