# Ansible loop - how to match up template values with with_items?

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I'm trying to create files that have values that match their `with_items` values.

I have a var list like so:

```
 sites:
   - domain: google.com
     cname: blue
   - domain: facebook.com
     cname: green
   - domain: twitter.com
     cname: red
```

I create individual files for each of the objects in the list in this task:

```
- name: Create files
  template:
    src: file.conf
    dest: "/etc/nginx/conf.d/{{item.cname}}.conf"
  with_items: "{{sites}}"
```

These both work great. What do I need to have in my template file for it create a file called `blue.conf` and has `google.com` in it **only**.

I have tried a lot of variations. The closest I got to was this:

```
   server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
      {% for item in sites %}
        server_name  {{item.cname}}.es.nodesource.io;

        location / {
          proxy_pass {{item.domain}};
        }
      {% endfor %}
    }
```

That will create individual files, but every file has all the domains and cnames.

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31142369/how-to-use-template-module-with-different-set-of-variables

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You already have the variable `item` defined and passed to the template, so there is no need to loop again.

Try:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name  {{item.cname}}.es.nodesource.io;

    location / {
      proxy_pass {{item.domain}};
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I was way overthinking it. This works, thanks.  I guess I was thinking that it got the template items from variables defined somewhere, not passed in from the task.